# Spring boot log4j2 database appender

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to use log4j2 database appender in a Spring boot project. I don't need any other database use in my project. I tried creating a ConnectionFactory using commons-dbcp2 and commons-pool2 (used sample codes available ), but unfortunately, Spring boot is failing during Startup, stating that it's unable to access ConnectionFactory. Seems like log4j2 is initialized before the ConnectionFactory. Is there a simple way to integrate log4j2 database appender in Spring boot, or it's something not possible? I don't want to make it complicated, and might use a different toolset, if these frameworks are not supposed to collaborate in a simpler manner.
Code that I used for ConnectionFactory:

```
DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(databaseUrl, properties);
PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, null);
GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>(
            poolableConnectionFactory);
poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);
this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection>(connectionPool);
```

Comment: Can you share your code, pom.xml and stacktrace?

Comment: Never mind. I resolved the issue by using jndi instead of connectionFactory. Also found out the issue why ConnectionFactory was not working. I was using @Value to populate properties like username, password and url in ConnectionFactory, but that was not getting populated. Not sure if there is a way to populate those properties, before loading log4j2.